# findOne() method is continuously returning null though data is available in DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

0

I am trying to get mongoose return data from Atlas MongoDB instance. connectivity is working fine cause registering new user has been successfully done, but while make a login attempt when i'm trying to retrieve data from DB to generate token, in response the user i'm receiving is null.

`here using of find one method----`

```
app.post('/login', async (req, res)=>{
    await User.findOne({username: req.body.username}).then(user => {
        if(!user){
            console.log(user)
            return res.status(401).send({
                success:false,
                message: "could not find the user"
            })
        }
        if(!compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)){
            return res.status(401).send({
                success:false,
                message: "Password is in correct"
            })
        }

        const payload = {
            username : user.username,
            id: user._id
        }
       const token = jwt.sign(payload, "Ano String", {expiresIn: "1d"}) 

       return res.status(200).send({
        success:true,
        message: "Login successful",
        token : "Bearer " + token
    })
    })
})
```

`here is my DB connectivity--`

```
`mongoose.
    connect(MONGODB_URL)
    .then(() => {
        app.listen(PORT, () => {
            console.log(`Example app listening on port ${PORT}`)
        })
        console.log('connected to MongoDb')
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
```

`here is my schema--`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')


const userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        username: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
)

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Answer (score -1):

## findOne

Save the output of the **find One** method into the variable.

```
const findResult = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username })
```

## Schema

It is better to write Schema like this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const test = new Schema(
    {
        username: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
)
```

## Use Try Catch

**It is better to use try catch instead of then and catch**